# How to use \chapter in "\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}"

Tags: chapters, document-classes

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with up-to-date TeX systems
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % do you *really* need it?
\usepackage{datetime}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{construction}{Construction}
[section]
\newtheorem{observation}{Observation}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[subsection]
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem*{question}{Question}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise} 

\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\mf}{\mathfrak}
\newcommand{\mb}{\mathbb}
\newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\rra}{\rightrightarrows}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

\textheight 9.3in 
\textwidth 6.5in
\calclayout

% metadata

%\date{\today}


\title{something}
\author{someone} 
\address{somewhere}


\begin{document}
    %\today
\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I want to use \chapter in above document class. It is showing error saying 
 "undefined control sequence".

I tried using report document class. On \usepackage[english]{babel} it is saying "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]. \usepackage[english]". How can I change above document class so that I can use \chapter, \section   and all that? Did I add \usepakage that does not work in some documentclasses?

Comment: As mentioned in an answer amsartdoes not support chapters. Report does, if that did not work for you explain exactly what you tested

Comment: @daleif It is saying same "undefined control sequence"..

Comment: On exactly which command? Not `\chapter` Where does `\calclayout` come from? And never set margins by hand. Use `geometry` or similar.

Comment: @daleif On \usepackage[english]{babel} it is saying "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]. \usepackage[english]".. On  \calclayout, \address and \email it is showing "undefined control sequence". I copied from some one's file (I dont remember from where).. How to use geometry for margins?

Comment: Every package has a manual, do you self a favor and read it. If I take your mwe and switch it to report I only get an error on `\calclayout` and `\address`

Comment: @daleif `\calclayout` ***is*** the method to be used with AMS classes when you want to change the default page parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`amsart` is one of a template which supports Journal style, Please use `amsbook` instead of that, you can get the output:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsbook}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with up-to-date TeX systems
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % do you *really* need it?
\usepackage{datetime}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{construction}{Construction}
[section]
\newtheorem{observation}{Observation}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[subsection]
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem*{question}{Question}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise} 

\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\mf}{\mathfrak}
\newcommand{\mb}{\mathbb}
\newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\rra}{\rightrightarrows}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

\textheight 9.3in 
\textwidth 6.5in
\calclayout

% metadata

%\date{\today}


\title{something}
\author{someone} 
\address{somewhere}


\begin{document}
    %\today
\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\chapter{Test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked.. How can we increase the font, I am hoping to get a book font...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Glad to hear that the suggestion works... Do you want to increase the `fontsize` to the whole text or any particular part?

Comment: to the whole text

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Per template maximum size of the text was defined as `12pt`, if you need to increase more than this, then define your own...If the answer is useful, then please accept it by clicking the `tick mark`...

Comment: There is no error as such but "\calclayout" is showing in red saying unrecognized command.. samething with  \address and \email.. Do I need to worry about this or does it not make a difference?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Not sure what you exactly mean, can you provide some exampe? please...

Comment: In the minimal working example, I have written "\calclayout \title{something} \author{someone} \address{somewhere}".. When I run the file, there is no error but if  I scroll pointer over that, it is saying "unrecognized command".. I do not know how to say more clearly, sorry..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik What type of TeX engine you used, i.e., `MikTeX`, `Overleaf`, etc...

Comment: It is TexMaker.

Comment: Sorry, I am not using TeXMaker, I am using either WinEdt or Epsilon are my text editor...